# What is the best module for student registration form

Tags: 7, forms

What is the best module to use if i want to create a
student registration form for my website.

Some of the fields in this form is referred to taxonomy and content types as entities.

Im a novice user of drupal 7
and cant find any mdoule that does this, I keep getting FORM API tutorial in my seaches but I when I checked it involves a lot of programming.. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform) is pretty popular among Drupalers for registration forms. It is quite well supported and documented. It also has many cool in-built features and a few other 3rd party modules that bring in even more sizzle to the mix.

Good-luck to you friend & welcome to drupal.stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for a warm welcome.
I have tried it but my concern is it doesnt support using fields from taxonomy or content types.. Is there a work around for it?

Comment: @ARGO I think it could be helpful to better define your use scenario.  Why does a registration form need to refer to directly refer taxonomy terms?  You can recreate the list in the webform if you have a list of terms you want.  Typically, nodes are used if you want to display the registration information to the outside world.  Again a better description of your use scenario could be worthwhile here.

Comment: Hi Rider, sorry to get have given you limited info. Here is my case: 
We are selling courses. I have created a node (Content Type) that contains course titles and other info. They are more than 50 courses.
Come of the fields in the courses content type are linked in taxonomy such as course levels and duration. 

now I want to create a form that contain a list field displaying the available course titles and durations. I dont want to redo the titles by adding another list to webform's list configuration.

Comment: I want to keep it centralised so whenever I did changes in the title from the course content type Its reflected in the form list as well. What do you think?

Comment: @ARGO: You may be stuck with a custom content type which anonymous users can create but not view/edit/delete. Or perhaps require signup so they can edit their own registration/s. One of my biggest problems with Webform is that it doesn't support the Fields API (and CCK before it), meaning that you're stuck with the very few fields that it provides itself. Fieldable webform submissions would have been a hugely awesome feature, but I fear that ship sailed long ago.

Comment: I agree Matthew, it could have been more awesome if it supports fields just like Entityforms module. I guess im really going for content type for now.